# Torus minus a point homeomorphic to sphere with three points?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

I was able to show they are both homotopy equivalent to $S^1 \wedge S^1$. I cannot find any reason why they would not be homeomorphic, but I also cannot see any way to construct an explicit map. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: A standard way to prove such statements is to use cohomology with compact support: $H^1_c(T^2- p)\cong Z^2$, $H^1_c(S^2-\{p_1,p_2,p_3\})=0$. Cohomology with compact support is a topological invariant but not a homotopy-invariant. (It is only invariant under proper homotopy-equivalence.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you take a loop $\gamma$ which goes once around the torus $\Bbb T^2$ (and doesn't go on the point $p$ which was removed) then the complement of $\gamma$ in $\Bbb T^2-p$ is still connected.

The complement of any loop $\gamma$ in $\Bbb S^2-\{p_1,p_2,p_3\}$ is disconnected (because of Jordan curve theorem basically). Therefore they can't be homeomorphic.

Comment: Has this got something to do with genus?

Comment: @WhySee I don't see a relation between genus and this argument.